# HTML 5 Video with music in Chrome is without music in Safari

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, video, safari

I have some trouble with Safari. I have a video on this page:
https://strategicbim.it 
and it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

I tried to watch it on Safari and, only on Safari, is muted. But I don't want that and I never write the word "*muted*" in my code.

What I supposed to do?

**This is my code:**

```
<video 
  id="myvideo" 
  controls="true" 
  height="auto" 
  loop="" 
  preload="auto" 
  width="100%">
<source  
  src="extrasmall_videoeng.mp4" 
  type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: audio plays in Safari for me... are you trying Safari on Windows as that's no longer supported!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this page in Safari, and the audio is working!

Is it possible that your browser is muted?

The only limitation for audio on safari with video that I'm aware of is that video tags with the attribute `autoplay` will not play with sound initially. As long as you don't have that attribute you should be fine.

Here is a picture of safari when the tab is muted (note the muted icon to the right of the url)

[image: browser muted]

And here it is unmuted (blue icon)

[image: browser unmuted]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Yesterday I finally understand that the problem is the mp3 audio inside the mp4 video, Safari doesn't read it.
So I edit the audio in the video from mp3 to AAC and now it works!

Hopes this can help others.